# Google Maps API: get two locations distance and plot on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am new at Google Maps. I want to the get distance from one place to another place and plot it on a map.

e.g: Place1 and Place2 
Distance - xxx Km (xx miles)
and plot it on map.

Please [take a look](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6kdPzOM0lGtSkxNOEdZUmlEczg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) computeDistanceBetween() function.  If you don't have the coordinates, use the [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) to get them.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geometry-headings-dist.html) (based off of [the example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings) in the documentation)