# Method to calculate distance between two points

Tags: google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Which one is best method to calculate the distance between two points using Google Map V3 API?

1. Using Google's Distance Matrix
2. `computeDistanceBetween()` method which is defined in `google.maps.geometry.spherical` namespace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542052/google-maps-api-get-two-locations-distance-and-plot-on-map

Comment: These two methods generally show different Kilometers results.In this case, how i choose which one is best?

Comment: What distance do you require? 1.is Direct line or 2.is  Travelling distance.

Comment: choose 2 locations that you know the distance beween and then choose the one that matches best.

Comment: @ David,Actually i want to calculate the traveling distance.

Comment: `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` computes the air distance while `google.maps.DistanceMatrixService` computes the road distance.  So there's no best, it depends on what distance you want to compute.

Answer (score 2):

(#2) computeDistanceBetween() returns the straight line distance, to get the driving distance, use either (#1) the Distance Matrix or (#3) the Google Maps API v3 [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), see the documentation for examples

[reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService)